# Are a Paladin's auras considered magical for the purpose of Anti-Magic Field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, paladin, antimagic-field

I know in current editions they don't explicitly state that the auras for paladins are based on magic.

I haven't ran into this yet, but my question is, does the effect provided from an aura penetrate anti-magic?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you imply, anti-magic affects "spells and magical effects". Spells are obvious. Magical effect means an effect created/sustained by magic - either a spell or magic item.

D&D 5e says what it means and means what it says: unless an ability is called out as magical or a spell then it is neither.

The paladin's aura is not identified as magical so it isn't and is unaffected by an antimagic zone. Neither is their ability to lay on hands, however, a *Potion of Healing* is because it is a "*magical* red fluid" or a *Cure Wounds* spell is because its a spell.

Indeed, most class features are not magical in any way. Exceptions include:

- All classes' **spellcasting** abilities (duh)
- Barbarian's Totem effects: "... your totem spirit fills you
  with supernatural might, adding **magical** fuel to your
  barbarian rage"
- Cleric's and Paladin's Channel Divinity: "... using that energy to fuel
  **magical** effects."
- Druid's Wild Shape: "... to
  **magically** assume the shape ...". Its debatable if this would cause you to change back or if an antimagic field would only prevent you from "assum[ing] the shape"
- Druid's and Monk's Timeless Body: "... the primal **magic** that you wield
  causes you to age more slowly." You'd have to spend a long time in an antimagic zone for this to be noticeable though.
- Fighter's Weapon Bond: "... that creates a **magical**
  bond ...".
- Monk's Ki: "... a **magical** energy that most
  monastic traditions call ki."
- Paladin's Divine Health: "... the divine **magic** flowing through you
  makes you immune to disease."
- Paladin's Aura of Warding: "... ancient **magic** lies so heavily
  upon you that it forms an eldritch ward."
- Sorcerer's Draconic Resistance: "As **magic** flows through your body, it causes physical
  traits of your dragon ancestors to emerge." Like Wild Shape its debatable that you would lose these in an antimagic field as it can be read that magic creates them but doesn't sustain them.
- Sorcerer's Bend Fate: "... twist fate
  using your wild **magic**."
- Warlock's Eldrich Invocations: "... imbue you with an abiding **magical** ability."
- Warlock's Entropic Ward: "... **magically** ward yourself ...".
- Wizard's Arcane Ward: "... weave **magic** around
  yourself ...".
- Wizard's Hypnotic Gaze: "... **magically** enthral ..."
- Wizard's Command Undead: "... use **magic** to bring
  undead under your control ..."
- Wizard's Transmuter's Stone: "... creating a
  transmuter’s stone that stores transmutation **magic**."

Comment: Only those Ki Abilities that allow you to cast spells are affected as far as I am aware or is that what you mean and not Ki in general? I understand the reading of Lay on Hands and your conclusion but it seems an oversight and a stretch for me to allow it in my games since it is not even necessarily "Divine" anymore.

Comment: A quote or citation for that last sentence would really strengthen this answer

Comment: You have quoted flavor text for Ki, however it appears Crawford indicates that unless the specific Ki ability explicitly says it is magical it is not considered so. Getting a bit off topic from OP but it does support the notion that Aura and LoH are not explicitly called out as magical in any text so by RAW this seems to be the correct answer unless future rulings from the team override them. http://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/11/06/ki-vs-antimagic/

Comment: @Slagmoth he can play it as he wants, I'll play it as it's written

Comment: @DaleM I would be interested in how you play Paladin then, as the flavor text is entirely contradictory to playing it any way other than LG. And I assume you know that Crawford actually had a hand in writing the rules and is the only citable source as he is pretty much the final say on Sage Advice? As you say though any DM is empowered to play their way... there is not a table that doesn't use house rules.

Answer (score 9):

While I believe that Dale M's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88570/48249) is correct, the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) (page 18) also clarifies:

> Determining whether a game feature is magical is straightforward. Ask
> yourself these questions about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?

Since the answer is No to each of the questions, a [Paladin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin)'s aura would **not** be considered magical.