# Is the Channel Divinity feature negated in an antimagic field, since it channels "divine energy"?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, religions-and-deities, antimagic-field

Are Channel Divinity powers not usable in antimagic fields?

The [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell says, in part (emphasis mine):

> Spells and other magical effects, **except those created by [...] a deity**, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

However, the [Channel Divinity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ChannelDivinity-110) feature says (emphasis mine):

> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to channel **divine energy** directly from your deity, using that energy to fuel magical effects.

Thus my confusion.

Comment: Related: "[Are a Paladin's auras considered magical for the purpose of Anti-Magic Field?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88569)", "[How to decide if an effect is magical for Magic Resistance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99335)", and "[How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364)"

Answer (score 11):

As per [a Jeremy Crawford tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/693210791978233857):

> Channel Divinity creates magical effects (stated in both the cleric and the paladin). [...]

From the PHB:

> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to channel divine energy directly from your deity, using that energy to fuel **magical effects.**

So they would not work inside an [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) which states:

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

There seems to be some confusion centred around whether the deity is creating the magical effect or whether it is simply suppling the power for the Cleric/Paladin to use to create the effect. Channel Divinity states that you use the divine energy to **fuel** a magical effect. To me this is very, very different from the deity creating the effect itself.

Lets looks at one example:

> Sacred Weapon. As an action, **you** can imbue one weapon that you are holding with positive energy

So, to me and I don't think I'm stretching the interpretation here, the deity provides the energy for an effect that the PC creates. Hence the PC's effect will not take effect in a AMF.

Comment: Per Antimagic field "...spells and magical effects, except those created by an artifact or deity...." Per Channel divinity "....to channel divine energy directly from your deity, using that energy to fuel magical effects." Thus my confusion.

Comment: @VittorioCarano: You should edit that clarification into the question itself, if that is the source of your confusion/uncertainty. (I've done so now.)

Comment: Yeah, this answer's own citations make it look wrong.  Not sure it _is_ wrong - but the two citations clearly show a reason the exception in AMF could apply to Channel Divinity.

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Instead, you should edit your answer as a whole to read as if it were always the best version of itself; anyone interested in older versions can view the revision history. (Also, it may be worth pointing out the difference between how the Channel Divinity feature is described for clerics and for paladins; the phrasing in the comment above is from the cleric version.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to agree with Steve's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/162777/48249), and say **yes**. According to the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) (page 18):

> Determining whether a game feature is magical is straightforward. Ask
> yourself these questions about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?

Since the answer to the last question is **yes** for the effects of Channel Divinity, those effects would indeed be negated in an Antimagic Field.

On the same page, there  is also:

> **Does a creature with Magic Resistance have advantage on saving throws
> against Channel Divinity abilities, such as Turn the Faithless?**
> Channel Divinity creates magical effects (as stated in both the cleric
> and the paladin). Magic Resistance applies.